# How convert multiple keys into single of dictionary and create Dictionary with multiple values per key in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested-lists

I have nested dict. like this I am getting this data from Api ,this is nothing but data_response:

```
    {
    "Parameter_1": {
        "2021-11-16 14:29:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:16:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:17:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-17 00:00:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:01:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:02:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-18 00:00:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:01:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:03:00": 355.45,
},
    "Parameter_2": {
        "2021-11-16 14:29:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:16:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:17:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-17 00:00:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:01:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:02:00": 335.48,
         "2021-11-18 00:00:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:01:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:03:00": 355.45,
}
```

This is a code I does:

```
data = []
for parameter in parameters:
    for key, values in data_response.items():
        for key1, value in values.items():
            date = key1.split(" ")[0]

    value_list = [value for key1, value in values.items()]
    data.append(value_list)
```

**Output I am getting in data is only values :**

Data :[[319.56,319.56, 319.56, 335.48,335.48,335.48,355.45,355.45,355.45]]

**I wish to get values of key ,with only single date. Expected output is:**

**Output Expected 1:**

```
{
    "Parameter_1": {
        "2021-11-16: [319.56,319.56,319.56],
        "2021-11-17": [335.48,335.48,335.48],
        "2021-11-18": [355.45,355.45,355.45],
},
    "Parameter_2": {
        "2021-11-16": [319.56,319.56, 319.56],
        "2021-11-17": [335.48,335.48,335.48],
        "2021-11-18": [355.45,355.45,355.45],
}
```

**Output Expected 2:**

```
Date:
     [
      parameter1[2021-11-16][2021-11-17][2021-11-18],
      parameter2[2021-11-16][2021-11-17][2021-11-18]
     ]
Values:
     [
      parameter1[319.56,319.56,319.56][335.48,335.48,335.48][355.45,355.45,355.45],
      parameter2[319.56,319.56,319.56][335.48,335.48,335.48][355.45,355.45,355.45]
     ]
```

Can you please help me to achieve my output ?

Comment: In "Parameter_1" and "Parameter_2",  I would like to assume that the data structure of the value is a list of floats (i.e. `List[float]`). Is that correct? Or is it something else? A string maybe?

Comment: Yes Its Correct

Comment: Well, probably because at this point "2021-11-16": 319.56,319.56,319.56, you do not have a string nor array of values; I think you need to pick which one you want and create a new dict that is of the correct type. which one do you want?

Comment: I want like this {
    "Parameter_1": {
        "2021-11-16: [319.56,319.56,319.56],
        "2021-11-17": [335.48,335.48,335.48],
        "2021-11-18": [355.45,355.45,355.45],
},
    "Parameter_2": {
        "2021-11-16": [319.56,319.56, 319.56],
        "2021-11-17": [335.48,335.48,335.48],
        "2021-11-18": [355.45,355.45,355.45],
}

Comment: See my answer for "Output Expected 1". I have no idea what "Output Expected 2" is meant to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
d = {
    "Parameter_1": {
        "2021-11-16 14:29:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:16:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:17:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-17 00:00:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:01:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:02:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-18 00:00:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:01:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:03:00": 355.45,
},
    "Parameter_2": {
        "2021-11-16 14:29:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:16:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:17:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-17 00:00:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:01:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:02:00": 335.48,
         "2021-11-18 00:00:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:01:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:03:00": 355.45,
}}

r = dict()

for k, v in d.items():
    r[k] = dict()
    for k_, v_ in v.items():
        r[k].setdefault(k_[:10], []).append(v_)

print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Parameter_1': {'2021-11-16': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56], '2021-11-17': [335.48, 335.48, 335.48], '2021-11-18': [355.45, 355.45, 355.45]}, 'Parameter_2': {'2021-11-16': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56], '2021-11-17': [335.48, 335.48, 335.48], '2021-11-18': [355.45, 355.45, 355.45]}}
```

Comment: Can You help me to find length of values getting in every dates seperately

Comment: @ShwetaShinde Use the built-in *len()* function on the lists associated with each date key

Comment: can you please explain I am trying to find the length in same program but getting error object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: can you please explain I am trying to find the length in same program but getting error object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: @ShwetaShinde This is clearly a new issue. I suggest you create a new question and show the updated code you're having trouble with

Comment: I shared with this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110953/find-the-length-of-values-of-nested-dictionary-and-create-new-dictionary-of-sa

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110953/find-the-length-of-values-of-nested-dictionary-and-create-new-dictionary-of-sa

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty clean data, and Pandas would handle it really well:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Parameter_1": {
        "2021-11-16 14:29:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:16:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:17:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-17 00:00:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:01:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:02:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-18 00:00:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:01:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:03:00": 355.45,
},
    "Parameter_2": {
        "2021-11-16 14:29:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:16:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-16 15:17:00": 319.56,
        "2021-11-17 00:00:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:01:00": 335.48,
        "2021-11-17 00:02:00": 335.48,
         "2021-11-18 00:00:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:01:00": 355.45,
        "2021-11-18 00:03:00": 355.45,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).reset_index()
df['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index']).dt.date.astype(str)
output = df.groupby('index').agg(list).to_dict()
print(output)
```

Output: (Formatting added manually)

```
{
    'Parameter_1': {
        '2021-11-16': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56], 
        '2021-11-17': [335.48, 335.48, 335.48], 
        '2021-11-18': [355.45, 355.45, 355.45]
    },
    'Parameter_2': {
        '2021-11-16': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56], 
        '2021-11-17': [335.48, 335.48, 335.48], 
        '2021-11-18': [355.45, 355.45, 355.45]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import Dict, List

def output_expected_1(json: Dict[str, Dict[str, float]]) -> Dict[str, Dict[str, List[float]]]:
    """Parse the input json argument and return required output which is a
    dictionary with a label key and a value of a list of floats. The datatime string is 
    truncated from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to YYYY-MM-DD (date).

    Given the arg json as:
    {
        "Parameter_1": {
            "2021-11-16 14:29:00": 319.56,
            "2021-11-16 15:16:00": 319.56,
            "2021-11-16 15:17:00": 319.56,
            "2021-11-17 00:00:00": 335.48,
            "2021-11-17 00:01:00": 335.48,
            "2021-11-17 00:02:00": 335.48,
            "2021-11-18 00:00:00": 355.45,
            "2021-11-18 00:01:00": 355.45,
            "2021-11-18 00:03:00": 355.45,
        },
        "Parameter_2": {
            "2021-11-16 14:29:00": 319.56,
            "2021-11-16 15:16:00": 319.56,
            "2021-11-16 15:17:00": 319.56,
            "2021-11-17 00:00:00": 335.48,
            "2021-11-17 00:01:00": 335.48,
            "2021-11-17 00:02:00": 335.48,
            "2021-11-18 00:00:00": 355.45,
            "2021-11-18 00:01:00": 355.45,
            "2021-11-18 00:03:00": 355.45,
        }
}



    Output would be:
    {
        'Parameter_1': {
            '2021-11-16': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56],
            '2021-11-17': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56],
        },

        'Parameter_2': {
            '2021-11-19': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56],
            '2021-11-22': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56],
        },
    }
    """
    output_dict = {}
    nested_dict = {}
    for label, content in json.items():
        for each_date_time, each_float in content.items():
            if not each_date_time[:10] in nested_dict.keys():
                nested_dict[each_date_time[:10]] = []
            nested_dict[each_date_time[:10]] = nested_dict[each_date_time[:10]].append(
                each_float) or nested_dict[each_date_time[:10]]

        output_dict[label] = nested_dict
        nested_dict = {}
    return output_dict
```