# Find the length of values of nested dictionary . And create new dictionary of same but with the percent of length

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested

[Code done before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72108690/how-convert-multiple-keys-into-single-of-dictionary-and-create-dictionary-with-m/72108924?noredirect=1#comment127413035_72108924)

Here I am getting the data like this:

```
{'Parameter_1': {'2021-11-16': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56], '2021-11-17': [335.48, 335.48, 335.48], '2021-11-18': [355.45, 355.45, 355.45]}, 'Parameter_2': {'2021-11-16': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56], '2021-11-17': [335.48, 335.48, 335.48], '2021-11-18': [355.45, 355.45, 355.45]}}
```

**Now I wish to find length of the values of this [319.56, 319.56, 319.56].
And then with the help of length I am counting the percentage of values are getting in one that single day.**
So here I does this:

```
data=dict()
    for parameter in parameters:
        for key, values in data_response.items():
             data[key]=dict()
             for key_, value_ in values.items():
                data[key].setdefault(key_[:10],[]).append(value_)

    raw_data = []
        for key, values in data.items():
            for key1, value in values.items():
                total_data_count = len(value)
                percentage_data = (total_data_count * 100)/1440
                available_data = str(percentage_data)[:5]
                raw_data.append(available_data)
```

Here in raw_data I am getting percentage of data like this

```
['31.94', '92.36', '93.12', '32.29', '92.56', '93.19']
```

Now the key date and this percentage values I wish to store in one dict

**Expected Output:**

```
{'Parameter_1': {'2021-11-16': 31.94 , '2021-11-17': 92.36, '2021-11-18': 93.12}, 'Parameter_2': {'2021-11-16': 32.29, '2021-11-17':92.56 , '2021-11-18': 93.19}}
```

Comment: Why don't you create the final dictionary directly in the loop, instead of creating `raw_data` as a list? You already have all you need, respectively in `key`, `key1`, and `available_data`

Comment: but how can I create that final dict.. when I am trying to  find the length in same program but getting error object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: Please post the full traceback for the error. Although, since you have only one call to `len()`, I suspect the issue may be that when you have a single value it is not included in a list?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some inconsistencies in your question: expected values are floats but you append strings to your list, the percentage calculation doesn't really makes sense to me (only dependent on the list length thus always the same in your example) but it might with complete data. Also it's not clear what `parameters` is (`parameter` is never used)

Nevertheless I think you're over-complicating the problem and a single nested loop might do what you need:

```
data_response = {'Parameter_1': {'2021-11-16': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56], '2021-11-17': [335.48, 335.48, 335.48], '2021-11-18': [355.45, 355.45, 355.45]}, 'Parameter_2': {'2021-11-16': [319.56, 319.56, 319.56], '2021-11-17': [335.48, 335.48, 335.48], '2021-11-18': [355.45, 355.45, 355.45]}}

data = dict()

for key, values in data_response.items():
    data[key]=dict()
    for key1, value in values.items():
        data[key][key1] = round((len(value) * 100)/1440, 2)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'Parameter_1': {'2021-11-16': 0.21, '2021-11-17': 0.21, '2021-11-18': 0.21}, 'Parameter_2': {'2021-11-16': 0.21, '2021-11-17': 0.21, '2021-11-18': 0.21}}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your response but when i am  passing  len() to value its giving me this error object of type 'float' has no len(). because of this I create that second loop

Comment: Could you write your question as a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you posted cannot be run as is.